# trying to return a list instead of NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I have a function that calls the DB to get the business information for a specific user. I run it and it returns an object formatted like the following:

```
(614, 10, 503, '', '', '', '', '', 'null', None, None, None, None, None, '', 'F&B', 'Other', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 4, 17, 46, 18), None, datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 18, 17, 46, 17), None, 0, None, None, None, 1, 0, None, None)
```

--

When I get the value, I append it into a list. The overall list is being in this format

```
(val1, val2, val3) (val1, val2, val3)......
```

So my issue, in this case, is, I need to select specific value to validate it but I can't because of the `NoneType list` that I get

full function:

```
def check_subscription(ids):
    count = 0
    length = len(ids)-1
    all_businesses = []
    paid_user = []
    while count <= length:
        q = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME where user_id = "+ str(ids[count])
        data = db.connect_once(q)
        all_businesses.append(data)

        count += 1
        #26
    count = 0
    while count <= (len(all_businesses)-1):
        print (all_businesses[count])
        count += 1
```

DB Function:

```
def connect_once(q):
# Open database connection
db = pymysql.connect("CONNECTION DETAILS" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute(q)
data = cursor.fetchone()
#print (data)

# disconnect from server
db.close()
return data
```

So the question that I need an answer to is the following:

1- can I change the type of the type/kind of returns values from `NoneType` to `List`? Is there any problem with my code that I made by mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to add in a check to ensure you have data present when you run `connect_once` by testing whether `cursor.fetchone()` has returned `None` or not. You could do it as part of the `connect_once` method:

```
def connect_once(q):
...
# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute(q)
data = cursor.fetchone()
if data == None:
    # do something, e.g. throw an error, set 'data' to be an empty list, etc.
db.close()
return data
```

or as part of `check_subscription`:

```
def check_subscription(ids):
    ...
    while count <= length:
        q = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME where user_id = "+ str(ids[count])
        data = db.connect_once(q)
        if data == None:
             # throw an error or whatever
        else:
            all_businesses.append(data)
        count += 1
    count = 0

    while count <= (len(all_businesses)-1):
        print (all_businesses[count])
        count += 1
```

You can decide the appropriate action (raising an error, ignoring the result and continuing, etc.) according to the needs of your script.

Comment: As I understood from the documentation, it will always return a NoneType (PyMySQL package). This will validate if the return is None (which is). Can I append these NoneType values into a List so I can select the data I need?

Comment: It would be helpful to have a bit more context about what you're trying to do with this code as there might be a simpler way to solve the problem - e.g. a DB query that could solve it directly. What is the output of `check_subscription` supposed to be?

Comment: actually, you're right. I added more complexity to it I can solve it with a select statement. but the main issue will remain, how can I select values from this return NoneType list?. I looked into the main files of the package, I got something that can return the results as a list but still showing errors. I got `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. tool name is `PyMySQL`.

Comment: What result are you trying to get? PyMySQL just handles the database interaction; I don't know what you want to do with the data you pull from the database as the code you have posted for `check_subscription` only goes as far as collecting and printing your DB query results. E.g. are you trying to get a mapping of `user_id` to business or subscription info?

Comment: I'm trying in this function to get the paid users and sort them in a list so I can deal with all notifications functions (many many functions). I'm having the issue of a type that I can't deal with. Thanks a lot for the help man. I think I got something to convert `NoneType` into `Dict`.